# How to restore file copy / transfer status window?

Tags: window, files, transfer

I'm working on ubuntu 11.10 GNOME Classic.

I copying file(~40GB) to External HD. while file copy in progress I mistakenly minimized the status window. After that I cant reopen that status window. b'z of that I cant identify whether that the transmission has completed or not. pls. help to restore the status window or how can I know the status of that transmission.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Go to file browser window.
2. Now <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> to switch between grouped windows, this also shows the hidden progress status window.

**FYI:**

- <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> → Switch between open windows
- <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd>   → Switch between grouped windows

Comment: Doesn't work on Ubuntu 14.04 (alt-tilde works, but there is no file progress window in the group, though the Unity bar icon clearly has a small progress icon)

Comment: Yep, Does not work on 14.04 @nmz787 Did you found any solution?

Comment: Right click Files > Show copy dialog

Comment: If its not working, and Right-click show copy dialog doesn't work either, you are seeing the bug  that @jpkc mentioned in his answer.

Comment: 4 years later, and the bug persists in 16.04 .. no wonder people switch to OSX

Comment: Does not work on 16.04. @Hitechcomputergeek's solution works (same as option #2 in [jpkc's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/310101/289003))

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04: open any folder then press alt ` (alt tilde) none of the other options worked. Pressing alt ` on the desktop wont do  it.

Comment: Doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04 for me either. I'm sure I have seen this problem in all versions since at least 11.  However the bug is not limited to Nautilus and file copying, I have seen non-modal windows disappear from other application too.  A quick search shows that others have had this problem too, for example  https://askubuntu.com/questions/612858/modal-windows-disappear-in-ubuntu-when-show-desktop-button-or-shotcut-is-used  and

Comment: @DAB is the mentioned solution works? I switched to osx couldn't check myself.

Comment: @Baya My problems seemed to be all in the Unity shell that ships with 16.04. I have played around with gnome-shell for the last few hours and have found it to be much more reliable. I

Answer (score 18):

First of all: Check your Files icon in the launcher (on your left for most systems). There will be a little progress bar over if it if it's still copying something.

In that case, if you're lucky, you can restore it in tree ways:

- Look for a file copy icon in your system tray (upper right in most systems). If there's one, click it and the file transfer dialog will reopen
- Right click on the Files icon in the launcher (yes, the one with progress bar on it) and choose "show copy window"
- On your Files icon in your system tray (the one with a progress bar) are some small arrows in its left, one for each window. If you manage to click in the arrow, the corresponding window will open. Your copy window might be one of those

In the case none of this work for you, you might be seeing this bug

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1010132

Answer (score 3):

I know this might sound primitive, but, I seemed to get back the copy dialog when Alt+~ on 'desktop' - which as I faintly recall was the foreground application when I believe I had minimised the copy dialog in the first place.

What worked for me then?

1. Alt + tab to 'desktop' or the foreground application when copy dialog minimised
2. Alt + ~ to reveal copy dialog

Comment: Alt + ~ brings the applications windows list, this is the way to switch between windows in the same application. If you open +2 windows of a same application, lets say Firefox, you can switch between them using this key combination.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue, after minimizing the “File Operations” progress bar I could no longer restore the window; even after using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd>.

However, if you right click the file browser icon on the left and select “Show Copy Dialog” you should then be able to use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> to restore the progress bar window.

Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a change on Ubuntu 18, it shows a small icon on top bar, click that to show progress.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I changed my GPU from nvidia to Intel and the copy dialog came back.
(it will stay when you switch to nvidia.) and I'm not sure it was because of this:)

**Edit:**

I have installed nvidia drivers using [this](http://www.binarytides.com/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-14-04/) method. after you installed it, you can open Nvidia settings tool by this code:

`nvidia-settings`
and change your GPU from nvidia to intel .

reboot your system and it should come back.

Comment: tell me if it works for you;)

Comment: Please edit your answer and elaborate on what you did, providing step by step instructions.

Answer (score 0):

On the copy status window (in 16.04), I think I hit "go to panel" or a similar button on the dialog while copying a large (15GB) file. I could not recover the copy status window. Nautilus AFAIK does not show files sizes in Bytes but in "human readable" form. Even so, right-clicking on the target file, and choosing properties, Nautilus will show byte size and I can see it increasing. Also I know the size of the source so I know if it is getting close or not.

Another option - I had doublecmd open before I did the Nautilus copy. Navigating a doublecmd window to the target file will show it "pulsing" as it is copied. Also doublecmd seems to inherit the copy operation and shows its percentage status in a bottom row.

Answer (score -1):

If you have installed some nautilus extensions like `nautilus-open-terminal` and others, make sure you have ran  :

```
$ nautilus -q
```

Comment: downvote, since it quits the nautilus / windows explorer, `-q, --quit                  Quit Nautilus`