# Modal windows disappear in ubuntu when show desktop button or shotcut is used

Tags: unity, netbeans, intellij

If I'm using netbeans or intellij and I have a modal window opened like settings window and I used show desktop button or super+D in ubuntu, then the modal window will completely disappear and that causes the parent window to be inactive (which is normal behaviour until the modal window is closed) and I then have to force close the application. I have searched for any workaround or fix but couldn't find any.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried pressing `ALT` + `TAB` to switch to the window? Scroll to the program and keep holding `ALT` until the area expands into the open windows.

Comment: Normal minimize and restore works fine. the issue only happen when I use show desktop Super + D. If I used ALT + TAB before show desktop then it works fine but if I used show desktop once then modal window disappear and even ALT + TAB doesn't work. Also it appears in Launcher as one window anyway whether I used show desktop or not.

Answer (score 1):

My Solution:

Right Click on IntelliJ / Netbeans whatever Icon in the Taskbar and say : "Close / Shutdown". A new modal dialog should pop up and asking if you really want to close the program (or it tell's you that there are unsaved changes / sessions running etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Click on the netbeans/intellij launcher icon to get it focused then click on it once more. It will show all the opened windows for you to choose one.

Comment: Only ALT + TAB works to show other modal windows before I use show desktop, other than that it show as one window in the launcher so clicking on it's icon doesn't work.