# 16.04 - Copy Dialog disappears and nothing seems to work

Tags: files, transfer, copy

I am in the middle of a massive file transfer. 
The file transfer window either never shows up or disappears when I move to another folder. 
I have tried everything to bring it back and no, i did not press Super+D keys either.

The show copy dialog option you get when you right click on Files Icon on the left of the screen is not working.

Alt+Tab, Alt + ~ also not working

It is quite a troublesome thing when you cant figure this status, especially when your work involves a lot of copying/moving folders.

Please help!

Comment: I get exactly the same problem. Very frustrating.  There is even an option to "Show Copy Dialog" when you right click on the Launcher,  but this doesn't work for me. I have also noticed the same problem with non-modal windows elsewhere in Ubuntu. They are not brought to the foreground when you switch to a minimized window.  See also this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/612858/modal-windows-disappear-in-ubuntu-when-show-desktop-button-or-shotcut-is-used