# Show copy dialog not working

Tags: nautilus, copy

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I am doing copy and paste of large data from one drive to another. It took over 30 minutes.

When I am trying to see the status using right click to see **show copy dialog** nothing is happening.

I tried by double clicking on File Manager but no success.

Any idea?

Comment: I have (or at least had) this annyoing issue too. I believe it is gone after some update this summer, but not sure. I always ignored that.

Comment: Duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/q/955738/631600

Comment: If you want 'full control' of the copy process, you can use the command line tool **`rsync`**. It has a great number of options including several that show the progress.

Comment: This question posted by people in past but problem not solved in ubuntu updates. It will be good if we have windows 10 like option in task bar to navigate between different open windows and dialog box.