# Ubuntu 18 Detach Progress Bar

Tags: 18.04, filemanager, copy-and-paste

I am wanting to detach the progress copy/paste/delete bar. Is there any way to do this in Ubuntu 18? I have seen various solutions like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112874/how-to-restore-file-copy-transfer-status-window) and [this one](https://sourcedigit.com/21466-ubuntu-show-copy-dialog-not-working-ubuntu-nautilus-file-progress-bar/) but they all say I should see a "Show Copy Dialog" option.

When I right click on the Files icon, there is no option to "Show Copy Dialog" like the directions say on other posts.
[image: Right Click On Files]

I also do not see this option if I click on the actual mini progress bar on the open Files window.

[image: Right Click On Progress Bar]

This is the progress bar that I want to detach into its separate window which was the default on older versions of Ubuntu.
[image: Progress Bar I want to Detach]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this as a normal usr with the default file manager that comes with Ubuntu 18.04 and later. The behaviour of how progress is shown, has changed since older versions. The posts you linked to all refer to older versions.